# Backend application technology for an Angular front-end

Tags: ruby, node.js, angular

I apologize if this question is too open ended. But I am struggling to get some of the principles to get started diving into this.

I am planning to build a fairly small demo app out of this seed (based on Angular 2): https://vmware.github.io/clarity/get-started

I'd like to render in an Angular UI some basic data that I keep in a back-end Redis database.

I am trying to find out what application layer I should be using to sit in between Redis and the Angular UI.

I am currently thinking of either using Ruby (just because I am slightly familiar with it) or Node.js.

Part of my struggling is because I am confused about the relation between Node.js and Angular 2 and I am wondering whether using Node code can help me integrating better and more easily with Angular (than with Ruby).

Other than using the same language/syntax (js), I have the gut feeling that I could more easily run a Node "app.js" file with some trivial business logic that reads from Redis and pass the result onto the Angular application. At least I could run the app.js logic on the same http instance where I am running the Angular application (my assumption).

If I wanted to use Ruby I have to use some web framework (e.g. Rails or Sinatra) to serve requests coming from the Angular application (e.g. in Angular I will have to make calls to `http://myrubysrv/applogic`).

Other than the language and this deployment detail, I am just wondering if passing variable from the application logic component into the Angular application is going to be easier if I use Node or the level of effort is going to be exactly the same whether I use Node or Ruby.

Thanks.

Comment: My opinion: As angular's integration with the middle tier will be through REST calls in most instances, your choices are wide open. It's hard to say which is best as it depends on your individual situation. Probably the Node option has gained so much traction recently is because the back-end and front-end share a language and its simplicity.

Comment: Your question isn't a good fit for SO. Too much is unknown so we can only assume and guess for the unknown information, then try to give broad answers. SO is about detailed answers, in particular about detailed answers to programming problems. You're asking about architecture, which SO does touch upon, but code is the focus. Do more research then try things and then ask about problems with the code you write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have some options here. Angular 2+ apps compile to what is essentially just an `index.html` that will handle the loading of other necessary views. So, you just need something that is able to serve an `index.html` file, and your application API could live completely separate from your serving application. Depending on how you're hosting, you have a lot of options here (for example, GitHub pages hosting your frontend and your backend on Heroku.

Rails makes setting up an API-only application a breeze and works quite well with Redis. I would say it's definitely the easiest option here; if you do need to pass in environment-specific configs to the Angular app, there are ways to do this while bootstrapping the startup.

Node is always a good option, but I've never worked with Node-Redis so I couldn't tell you the hangups. I can also say that Rails would likely be easier.
However, [Angular Universal](https://universal.angular.io/) primarily supports Node, with the only other supported platform being .NET. If you want to use or mess with Universal (super cool stuff) Node would be needed, at least when serving the app.

Node would also offer a chance to brush up on your Typescript chops outside of Angular, if you are looking for a learning opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

Angular is agnostic to the backend you use. Just expose a REST endpoint either from your RUby or Node+Expres backend. The client will use something like this anyway:

```
http.get("/products").subscribe(...)
```

Take a look at these code samples where Angular talks to Node:
https://github.com/Farata/angular2typescript/tree/master/Angular4/http-node-samples